# Apple developer program share with another company

Tags: ios, iphone

Hi we wants to develop an App for a third party company. Apple just told us if we put the third party logo on the App we won't be able to publish the app on the App Store as we are not that third party company. They told us the other company will need to joined the developer program, add us a developer (we also need to join the developer program). Now my question is does this means the third party company will be able to see our source code ?

Comment: They can add you as a developer in their program. You can do rest everything yourself.

Answer (score 0):

They can only view the source if you give it to them.
When submitting an app to the Apple App Store, you submit the binary file which does not include the source.

Comment: ok so I send the binary file to my client, then they submit it to apple ?

Comment: You need to sign it with their distribution certificat before sending it to the client, then they will be able to submit it to apple ..... Else the third party company needs to add you also as app-manager to be able to submit apps to itunes on their-behalf.

Comment: Ok and if I become app-manager they won't see my source code ?

Comment: Again, they will only get the binary download, which does not include the source code.

Rule of thumb is, if you don't have to upload the source code (which you don't) then they won't see it.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not trivial to sign for somebody else. You need to request from that company that they create an account for you on their developer portal. Sometimes those companies refuse this and you need to go on one of their Mac to put your sources and compile/sign the code. 
I prefer to hack Xcode to let me generate an unsigned binary and send it to my customers in specific crafted Xcode projet so they can do the Archive process and sign with their own private distribution key. This method is not documented by Apple but works well.